# Convergence of Uniform random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $U$ be a Uniform[0,1] random variable. If we consider $[nU]$ where [] is the greatest integer function, then we know that $[nU]$ is a discrete uniform $\{1,2,...,n-1\}$ random variable. We know a few interesting properties related to this such as $[nU]/n\to U$. However I am trying to show that this convergence is not monotone. We can consider $P(U_{n+1}>U_n)$ and intuitively the answer should be $1/2$ (just uniform variables split further over the same interval). However I am unsure of how to prove such a result?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that $U_n:=[nU]/n$,
$$
\mathsf{P}(U_{n+1}>U_n)=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\mathsf{P}\!\left(\frac{i}{n+1}< U\le \frac{i}{n}\right)=\frac{1}{2}\times\frac{n-1}{n+1}.
$$

Comment: how did you get that summation?

Comment: $$
\{U_{n+1}>U_n\}=\bigcup_{i=1}^{n-1}\left\{\frac{i}{n+1}<U\le \frac{i}{n}\right\}.
$$

Comment: @PreMed95 the best way to see that is by drawing out two of your U_n s by drawing intervals [0,1] and slicing them. You can also do it rigorously by noting what U_n and U_{n+1} are in these intervals.

Comment: okay so why don't we fix a value for $U_n$ and then we take the summation over the choices. say $U_n=i/n$ for some $i=0,1,..n-1$. I need to find the probability $P(U_{n+1}>i/n)$. This will happen whenever $U_{n+1}=\frac{i+1}{n+1},...\frac{n}{n+1}$. I don't see how to relate this to the even inside the union however?